# UpdateByPk в yii2

Tags: yii2

Не могу найти аналог этого метода в yii2, может, кто подскажет?

В первом yii можно было сделать 1 запрос на обновление, вот так `User::model()->updateByPk(1,['type'=>2])` обновив у пользователя с id = 1 тип на 2. Во втором, судя по [найденной информации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#manipulating-data-in-database), это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
$user= User::findOne(1);
$user->type= 2;
$user->update();
```

А это уже 2 запроса.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#updateAll()-detail

Comment: @mountpoint, смотрел на этот метод, но каким-то нелогичным он мне показался.
т.е. получается мой пример будет выглядеть как-то так
`User::updateAll(['type' => 2], 'id = 1');`
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User::updateAll(['type' => 2], ['id' => 1]);
```

Т.к. вы используете AR, то Yii2 в любом случае делает как минимум один запрос на получение схемы таблицы `user`. т.е.

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user`
```

Comment: да, я уже понял, что придётся писать свой метод, который будет нести логичное название.
А на счёт получения схем и прочего, то это не страшно, эти данные всегда в кэше

Comment: @frgs Да, кэш, как вариант.